# MongoDB How target element with the same index in the list

Tags: mongodb

For a collection named col1, who have for attribute a list of sub Object named sub1.

sub1 have two attributes key, and name.

I want to do a query who select key=aa and name=John with key and name **from the same index**.

Example:

> col1
>
> Objectid(1)
>   sub1[{    key=aa,    name=lola   },
>   {key=bb, name=john   }]
>
> Objectid(2)
>   sub1[{    key=aa,    name=john   }]

return expected only Objectid(2)

i read the doc for $slice or $indexOfArray or $cursor but i don't know how to do.

thanks

Comment: use aggregation: first **`$unwind`** the `sub1` array and then filter using **`$and`** in a **`$match`** stage

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

I just report the answer done in comment by felix !